# Is there a way to show all the extension functions of a given Kotlin class in Intellij IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, extension-function

The only way I've found so far is to create an instance of the given class and then using the autocomplete to see all possible functions. Obviously, this way is cumbersome and takes too much time. Is there a neater way to see all possible functions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you select the class and right-click and select `Find Usages` then select `Group by type`, it will show you usages where the class is `Extension receiver type` (make sure `Group by test/production` is unticked if you want to see all the possible extensions together).

e.g. 
[image: Example find usages on List]