# How to list all Kotlin extension functions in project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-extension

Is here a way to list all Kotlin extension functions in a project / module in Android Studio?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336835/is-there-a-way-to-show-all-the-extension-functions-of-a-given-kotlin-class-in-in) way to list all extension functions for one class but nothing for all classes.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46336835/3422245

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, I came up with a solution using regex in Android Studio search that might be useful.

```
^(private|internal|public)? fun (.*\.)
```

But this doesn't cover the case where we don't have the visibility modifier explicitly, so it might be necessary searching for

```
^fun (.*\.)
```

as well.